# How to enable persistent cart for GUEST users?

Tags: cart

After enabling persistent cart in the Admin the cart stays active for logged in users only it appears. I want to keep the cart active for all users, including those who don't log in but come back to the site at a later date.

Is there a way to enable cart persistence for users who are not logged in?

Answer (score 1):

Since there will be no way to tell which user it is other than their browser session, the only thing you can really do is just increase the lifetime of their session.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022952/set-session-time-out-limit-for-magento-frontend

Comment: Thanks. I'm working to show remarketing ads to abandoned cart sessions. So, when the user clicks the ad and comes back to the site, they will see their cart loaded with the products they originally had. Can I accomplish that by extending the lifetime of their session as you suggest? Thank you again.

Comment: Well if the user is on another computer, then obviously their session isn't on multiple machines at the same time. If you're able to add additional info to the ads that contains their session information, you should be able to pass that along.

Comment: I just need to make sure their cart stays active on the machine they're on or corresponding email address.